# LSTM Graph execution error: incompatible shapes during training

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm still quite new at working with Deep Networks. I am trying to use an LSTM to perform (what I thought was) a simple binary classification using keras. My dataset is made up of chunks of text from novels, which I process with:

```
def process_data(data):
    texts = data['text'].tolist()
    labels = data['label'].tolist()

    tokenizer.fit_on_texts(texts)
    sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(texts)

    X_padded = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=2000)
    X_sliding_window, y_sliding_window = create_sliding_window_data(
        X_padded, labels)

    y_train_reshaped = np.expand_dims(y_sliding_window, axis=-1)

    return X_sliding_window, y_train_reshaped
```

Before feeding it to the BiLSTM:

```
def build_model(sequence_length, embedding_dim, batch_size):
    input_layer = Input(shape=(sequence_length,
                        embedding_dim), batch_size=batch_size)
    lstm = Bidirectional(
        LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, stateful=True))(input_layer)
    attention = Attention()([lstm, lstm])
    merged = Concatenate(axis=-1)([lstm, attention])
    output_layer = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(merged)

    model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
```

I have been struggling to understand why I get the following error, and how to fix it:

```
Graph execution error:

Detected at node gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/mul/Mul defined at (most recent call last):

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1807, in fit

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1401, in train_function

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1384, in step_function

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1373, in run_step

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1154, in train_step

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/optimizers/legacy/optimizer_v2.py", line 598, in minimize

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/optimizers/legacy/optimizer_v2.py", line 656, in _compute_gradients

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/optimizers/legacy/optimizer_v2.py", line 532, in _get_gradients

Incompatible shapes: [26,1] vs. [64,250]
         [[{{node gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/mul/Mul}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_4934]
```

The parameters I've used are:

```
sequence_length = 250
embedding_dim = X_train.shape[2] 
batch_size = 64
```

and I've checked the training shapes, which are y_train.shape: (218, 1) X_train.shape: (218, 250, 2000) and which seem alright to me... I have no idea where [26,1] would come from. Can someone help?